# Pegar o ID do usuário logado Python

Tags: python, django

Estou com um projeto em Python e Django. Onde tenho uma classe INSCRIÇÃO, e nessa tabela gostaria de gravar na coluna "Pessoa" o ID do usuário logado na aplicação, na coluna "Eventos" gravar o evento que ele esta fazendo inscrição, que no caso estou utilizando o Slug, para acesso deste evento.

```
class Inscricao(models.Model):
    pessoa = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name='usuario', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    evento = models.ForeignKey(Evento, verbose_name='evento', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    categoria = models.ForeignKey(Categoria, verbose_name='categoria', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    numero = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='número', blank=True)
    data_inscricao = models.DateField(verbose_name='data de inscrição', blank=True)
    detalhe = models.TextField(max_length=100, verbose_name='observação', blank=True)
```

Comment: A view que recebe essa requisição é instancia `Inscricao` recebe um `request`. Nesse request você pega os dados necessário (ex: `request.user` para usuário logado) e instancia seu Model com os dados corretos.

Answer (score 1):

Como já indicaram, o request já contem o logged user. Contudo, quando tens de utilizar para vários objetos, eu utilizo uma class abstract, e aqui defino o atributos que são sempre iguais, ou seja, quem criou e quando, quem atualizou e quando e reutilizo esta as vezes que quiser.

Contudo, implica instalar um package, podes fazer assim:

**pip install ai-django-core**

E defines o middleware assim:

**settings.py**

```
MIDDLEWARE = (
    ...
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'ai.middleware.current_user.CurrentUserMiddleware',
)
```

Começas por adicionar um ficheiro common.py:

**common.py**

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models
from django.utils.timezone import now
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from ai.middleware.current_user import CurrentUserMiddleware
from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericRelation

class CommonInfo(models.Model):
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, verbose_name=_("Created By"), blank=True, null=True, related_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s_created", on_delete=models.SET_NULL, editable=False)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True, null=True, editable=False)
    modified_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, verbose_name=_("Modified By"), blank=True, null=True, related_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s_modified_on", on_delete=models.SET_NULL) 
    modified_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, blank=True, null=True)

    @staticmethod
    def get_current_user():
        """
        Get the currently logged in user over middleware.
        Can be overwritten to use e.g. other middleware or additional functionality.
        :return: user instance
        """
        return CurrentUserMiddleware.get_current_user()

    def set_user_fields(self, user):
        """
        Set user-related fields before saving the instance.
        If no user with primary key is given the fields are not set.
        :param user: user instance of current user
        """
        if user and user.pk:
            if not self.pk:
                self.created_by = user
            else:
                self.modified_by = user

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.modified_on = now()
        current_user = self.get_current_user()
        self.set_user_fields(current_user)
        super(CommonInfo, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

**models.py**

```
from myapp.common import CommonInfo

class Inscricao(CommonInfo): # <= tens de adicionar aqui o CommonInfo ao invés do models.Model
    pessoa = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name='usuario', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    evento = models.ForeignKey(Evento, verbose_name='evento', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    categoria = models.ForeignKey(Categoria, verbose_name='categoria', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    numero = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='número', blank=True)
    data_inscricao = models.DateField(verbose_name='data de inscrição', blank=True)
    detalhe = models.TextField(max_length=100, verbose_name='observação', blank=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

O objeto request da view, se a mesma somente é acessada com usuário autenticado, conterá a  instância do user em request.user.